# How do I remove this mounting mechanism?

Tags: nikon, lens-mount, nikon-d3200, m42

I've bought some old lenses a while back (all M42 lens mounted lenses). I've decided to try and convert them to work on a Nikon Dslr, infinity focus and all. I succeeded on my first lens (first pictures), by replacing te mounting mechanism with a 3D printed one, it works flawless. It's awesome!

[image: New mounting plate]

However, I also have another lens, which I have high hopes for because it focusses beyond infinity when held up to my D3200. The problem is though, that I can't find a way for unmounting the mounting plate for replacement. I did try screwing off the side screws, it revealed a few philips head screws around the aperture ring, but I don't know if that's for the mounting plate or not... Anyone who has experience with the ones? Or is able to tell me if those screws are actually for the mounting plate?

[image: Top view]
[image: Side view 1]
[image: Side view 2]

Thanks in advance!

Jan-Willem

Comment: What lens is that (manufacturer and specs)? Some lenses are serviced completely from the front. I find them to be a pain to work on and wouldn't bother if it's just to change the mount. I'd try to find an adapter, as Sowsun has suggested.

Comment: The lens is a Panagor PMC 135mm f2.8-22. If it's as you say and I need to do it all from the front I'll just sell it I guess. I've tried these adapters, but they are always too thick so infinity focus is nowhere to be found after adding it.

Comment: The lenses I've seen that are accessed from the front are all Asahi Pentax/Takumar. In one of the photos, I see some screws in front of the aperture ring that might give you access to the mount. But it would be a pain to work on, unless you especially like the image quality of that lens...

Comment: What software, printer, etc did you use to make the 3D print? How much does it cost to print a mount?

Comment: Yeah I thought so about the screws around the aperture lens, when I screwed them open, it seemed that I was able to remove the mount, however as of yet my philip head screwdriver is broken, so I need to buy another one

Comment: I've printed the mount using Cura, just used a m42 -> Nikon adapter stl file. Then I just recessed the biggest ring into the platform so it would print thinner. Then I just measured the holes, and screwed it in. It was about 10 cents per adapter to print, I've printed 4 versions, so it costed me about 80 cents.

Comment: Consider getting JIS cross-type screwdrivers... They're slightly different from Phillips... Thanks for info... I'll have to look into Cura...

Comment: Aha! Didn't know there was a difference! Thanks! I'll order some I think

Comment: I'll keep you posted on my progress, I'll go buy a few screwdrivers this afternoon

Comment: There is no such thing as a “*beyond infinity*“ infinity is infinite

Answer (score 2):

I can't help you with disassembling that lens but since that lens will focus beyond infinity, I would either buy, or print yourself, a thin M42 to Nikon F adapter.

You can buy one like this for under $5.00

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the idea!  However I've tried these adapters, but they are always too thick so infinity focus is nowhere to be found after adding it. So that's why I wanted to replace the mount.

Comment: The one in my photo is VERY thin. Have you tried one like that?